# A question about the definition of continuous function.

Tags: calculus

The definition:
$f:D\to R$ is continuous at $x_0\in D$ if for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists some number $\delta>0$, such that for all $x\in D$:
$|x-x_0|<\delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(x_0)| < \epsilon$.

If a function is defined at x=2, but it is not defined at a specific delta environment of x=2, why the function is not continuous at x=2? and if it is, is it a vacuous truth for all $x\notin D$ ,$2-\delta < x < 2+ \delta $?
[image]

Comment: Perhaps Consider redrawing the x-axis by only adding in those points of D on which $f$ is defined. In other words, consider $f$ to be a function from a subset of $D$ rather than $D$ itself. Now, x-axis becomes a dashed line, instead of a continuous one. Now, 'vacousness' becomes clear, I think. I could be wrong though, but it seems to be interesting perspective.

Answer (score 5):

Such a function is vacuously continuous at $x=2$, as you surmised. If we take $\delta$ small enough, the only $x$ satisfying $|x-2|<\delta$ is $x=2$, and then $|f(x)-f(2)|=|f(2)-f(2)|=0<\epsilon$ is satisfied for any $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: Interesting. I've noticed this vacuous truth and asked my lecturer about it and he said that $2-\delta < x < 2+ \delta$ should be defined properly. I was not satisfied by his answer and asked here and it turns out I'm right.

Comment: He might not have understood what you meant.  But if $f$ is such that $f(x)$ is undefined for all $x \in (a,b)$ except for one $x_0 \in (a,b)$ where $f(x_0)$ is defined then.  The definition of continuity *does* apply.  For every $\epsilon > 0$ let $\delta = \min (x_0-a, b-x_0)$ then for all $x$ so that $|x-x_0| < \delta$ we have $x = x_0$ and $|f(x) - f(x_0)| = 0 < \epsilon$.  So continuous.  That $\delta$ is a constant and applies to every possible epsilon so that delta has *nothing* to do with epsilon at all, is not relevant.

Comment: "he said that 2−δ<x<2+δ should be defined properly".  It's not clear what he meant.  You are defining your function with delta in mind.  So he could be saying you must define delta in terms of the function and x_0 rather than the other way around.  But that's fine.  Do it the other way.  $f$ is undefined on $(2-k, 2)\cup(2, 2+k)$ but defined at $2$.  FOr any $\epsilon > 0$ let $\delta = k$.  THERE.  Now you *have* defined $\delta$ properly.

Comment: @fleablood He meant that all $2-\delta<x<2+\delta$ should be in the function's domain. What I claim is, if these values are not in the domain(meaning the function is not defined for them), except for one value, say x=2 in my example, so the definition is valid  vacuously( it is continuous at x=2) (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth), Because you can't prove that it isn't. For $2-\delta<x<2+\delta$ that are not in the domain you can't say anything, so its true that $|x-2|<\delta$ and $|f(x)-f(2)|<\epsilon$ for any $\delta$ and $\epsilon$ (for these  x values).

Comment: Then you are correct and he is wrong.  Unless we told specifically that $f:\mathbb R \to X$ in which case $f$ *is* defined for all $x$ in $\mathbb R$. However, a function such as $f(x) = \frac {x^2 +3 }{x-3}$ would "not count" as its domain is not $\mathbb R$ but only $\mathbb R - \{3\}$.  You are correct. It is vacuously continuous.  Which.. doesn't *feel* right (it "jumps") but it fits the letter of the law of the definition.

Comment: Someone else asked recently if functions on finite domains were continuous.  The upshot is they are vacuously. Any $f:\mathbb N \to X$ is vacuously continuous as well.  This wrecks havoc with the concept "continuous means you can draw the map without lifting your pencil from the paper" but they must follow if we want our definitions to be rigorous.

Comment: @fleablood The definition in my book says that x_0 should be in the domain. So the function you gave doesn’t fit for $x_0=3$The full definition in my book is: 1. $x_0$ should be in the domain. 2.the function has a limit when $x ->x_0$. 3. The limit when $x->x_0$ is f(x).

Comment: So my statement stands only when the delta environment of 3 is not in the domain.(and if 3 is in the domain).

Comment: Well, there is nothing wrong with $f (x_0)$ being defined but none other within a distance of $x_0$.  Bottom line, you are right and your instructor is not.

Comment: @fleablood I had a talk with my lecturer and he said we are wrong. If the function is not defined at $\delta$ environment of $x_0$ it’s not continuous at $x_0$.Because one of the demands is the existence of limit at this point, and one of the demands of the limit definition is a $\delta$ environment defined in the domain.

Comment: That could be.  And one can make formal and consistent definitions that a domain must be dense (any two elements have an element between them).  And then your lecturer would be right.  He'd even make sense as these loopholes that *shouldn't* be continuous wouldn't be.... But the thing is, I've *never* seen any text *make* that requirement.